# Xcode compiler error when adding @objc flag to method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Xcode is giving the following compiler error.

[image]

I assume it is complaining about using the `NSLayoutAttribute` enum. If it is complaining about this why isn't it complaining about the `NSLayoutRelation` enum. How do I write this method in a way that is compatible with Objective-C.

Comment: could it be that it complains about default values?

Comment: @RolandasR No. If I comment out the two lines with NSLayoutAttribute it is fine. Seems to be something with NSLayoutAttribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because Objective C objects cannot have arrays of things that are not NSObjects.

Edit for future searchers:
Erasing the type using AnyObject will make the warning disappear, however you will then need to be careful with casting.

Comment: I think you are right. When I replaced the `NSLayoutAttributes` with `AnyObjects` it compiled fine. Thanks.

Comment: Accept the answer? so that other people who have the same error get to this page and see that this solved the problem. It's a pretty common error.

Comment: I can't accept the answer within 10 mins. It must be some Stack overflow constraint. Will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error (even in a class that inherits from `NSObject`) is because some Swift types cannot be represented in Objective-C, such as an [array of enums](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30453961/2415822).

`[[NSLayoutAttribute]]` will not work but `[[Int]]` will because while `Array<SomeEnumType>` cannot be bridged, an array of `Int`s are implicitly bridged to an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` objects through Foundation.

Yoav Schwartz's answer is wrong because Objective-C objects **can** have arrays of things that are not `NSObject`s.  Look at C arrays:  `NSUInteger someNums[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` is valid in Objective-C.  `NSArray`s however, cannot hold value types and must hold objects.

Comment: Thats strange because I changed the `[[NSLayoutAttribute]]` to `[[Int]]` and it is compiling fine :\

Comment: @villy393 from your screenshot it looked like you had an optional 2D array of `NSLayoutAttribute`s: `[[NSLayoutAttribute]]?`  Removing the optional probably solved that issue.  Also, please post your full code rather than a screenshot in your question.

Comment: I changed it to `horizontalAttributes: [[Int]]? = nil,` and `horizontalRelations: [[Int]]? = nil,` which is still and optional 2D array and it is working fine. I suspected what you suggested as well but it turns out not to be right.

Comment: @villy393 Ah, actually the problem is not because of the optionals, it's because you're trying to bridge an array of enums to Objective-C, which is not supported.  `NSLayoutAttribute` is just an `Int`, and `Int` arrays can be bridged to Objective-C as an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` objects.  That's the real issue here.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @villy393 Hope my answer is clearer now, thanks for following up and correcting me!